# Any way to determine if adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth has triggered?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, uilabel

Is there anyway to determine if adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth has been triggered?  My app has a UILabel that takes up the entire view.  By using the UIPinchGestureRecognizer you can pinch in and out to change the font size.  Works great.  However, when the font reaches the max size for the UILabel, it displays bizarre behaviour.  The text in the UILabel moves down the UILabel.  Without adding `bannerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true` the text gets clipped.  I would like to know when the font is at the maximum size for the UILabel, and i will stop trying to increase the font size.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var bannerLabel: UILabel!

    var perviousScale:CGFloat = 0
    var fontSize:CGFloat          = 0
    var originalFontSize: CGFloat = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("pinch:"))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
        perviousScale = pinchGesture.scale

        bannerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

        originalFontSize = bannerLabel.font.pointSize
        fontSize         = originalFontSize

    }

    func pinch(sender:UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

        println("font size \(bannerLabel.font.pointSize)")

        if perviousScale >= sender.scale  //Zoom In
        {
            decreaseFontSize()

        }
        else if perviousScale < sender.scale  //Zoom Out
        {
            increaseFontSize()
        }

    }

    func threeFingers(sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        println("threeFingers")

    }

    override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {

        bannerLabel.font = UIFont(name: bannerLabel.font.fontName, size: fontSize)

    }

    func increaseFontSize(){

        bannerLabel.font = UIFont(name: bannerLabel.font.fontName, size: fontSize)

        fontSize = fontSize + 2.5

    }

    func decreaseFontSize(){

        bannerLabel.font = UIFont(name: bannerLabel.font.fontName, size: fontSize)

        if fontSize >= originalFontSize {

            fontSize = fontSize - 2.5
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you can add an observer:

1) Add the dynamic modifier to the property you would like to observe:

```
dynamic UILabel bannerLabel = UILabel()
```

2) Create a global context variable

```
private var myContext = 0
```

3) Add an observer for the key-path

```
bannerLabel.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth", options:.New, context:&myContext)
```

4) Override observeValueForKeyPath and remove observer in deinit

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject: AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if context == &myContext {
            println("Font size adjusted to fit width: \(change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey])")
        } else {
            super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
        }
    }

 deinit {
        bannerLabel .removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth", context: &myContext)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  How do I implement this, I've never used `.addObserver` before.  When I add the line, I get the following error: `Cannot invoke 'addObserver' with an argument list of type '(ViewController, forKeyPath: String, options: String, context: nil)'`

Comment: The `dynamic UILabel bannerLabel = UILabel()` gives me the following error  `Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'`